# Laravel - Saving an object with children from another object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a process/to do list that applies to students. There is the processes table, process_tasks table for its task children, then the students table, process_student table for the student processes and also the process_task_student table for corresponding tasks.

For example, "student registration" *process*, with the *process tasks* :

1. Enter student data
2. Save student file somewhere
3. Email the student

Process Model

```
public function tasks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProcessTask');
}
```

Student Model

```
public function processes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Process')->withTimestamps();
}
```

When I create the student, I create the necessary process/to do list for the student:

```
    $student = Student::create($request->all());
    $process = Process::findOrFail(1);
    $student->processes()->attach($process);
```

However, how would I attach all of $process (1) process tasks to the student as well?

**Attempt 2:** (Not working - nothing in process_task_student)

```
    $process = Process::findOrFail(1);
    $process->load('tasks');
    $student->processes()->attach($process);
    $student_process = $student->processes()->wherePivot('process_id', 1)->first();
    $student_process->tasks()->saveMany($process->tasks);
```

Comment: According to your relationships, a process has many students. a process has many tasks as well. but from your explanation it feels like, a student will have many processes, and each process will have many tasks and therefore a student will have many tasks through a process? did I get this right or am I way off?

Comment: i only provided one example above, but yes, a process has many tasks and a student can have many processes (and as you mentioned, consequently - many tasks, through a process)

Comment: in that case you do not need to directly link student and tasks. The process in the student model should be hasMany. You can create an additional relationship for student tasks in the student model; this can be a hasManyThrough relationship. Attaching process to student will suffice. You can query student tasks using the hasManyThrough.

Comment: another question, sorry, can one process belong to many students?

Comment: correct - one process can belong to many students

Comment: ah then disregard my previous comment. sorry. but the first sentence stands. you do not need to directly link students and tasks since tasks belong to a process. You can get tasks when you query using `with('processes.tasks')`

Comment: To clarify, I cant link directly to processes.tasks because each student has its own status for each task (complete/incomplete/etc) - hence the need for the pivot table process_task_student that has the process_task_id / student_id and the status

Comment: Added Attempt 2 for something else I tried, but not working...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217802/discussion-between-user3532758-and-supamonkey).